# stuck with centreon-vmware

Tags: monitoring, centos6

I'm using centreon to monitor vmware machine, I follow steps to install but at this step:

> yum install ces-plugins-Virtualization-VMWare-client

I stuck with the error, it returns:

> No package centreon-plugin-Virtualization-VMWare-client available.
>   Error: Nothing to do

What should I do to solve the problem ? please help, many thanks

Answer (score 1):

**You can try to search for the right package**

```
yum search vmware
```

These packages will show:

```
centreon-plugin-Virtualization-VMWare-daemon.noarch : Perl daemon to monitor VSphere Infrastructure
centreon-plugin-Virtualization-Vmware2-Connector-Plugin.noarch : Centreon plugin
centreon-plugin-Virtualization-Vmware2-Esx-Wsman.noarch : Centreon plugin
```

Install the first 2

Answer (score 1):

Centreon Plugin
Install this plugin on each needed poller:

```
# yum install centreon-plugin-Virtualization-Vmware2-Connector-Plugin
```

Installation of the VMware daemon
Install this daemon on each needed poller:

```
# yum install centreon-plugin-Virtualization-VMWare-daemon
```

Configuration of the VMware daemon

The daemon "centreon-vmware" has a configuration file "/etc/centreon/centreon_vmware.pm" of the following structure:

```
%centreon_vmware_config =   
    vsphere_server => {
                    'default' => {'url' => 'https://vcenter/sdk',
                                 'username' => 'XXXXXXX',
                                 'password' => 'XXXXXX'}
                    }, 
    port => 5700
};
```

Then start daemon with command:

```
# service centreon_vmware start
```

You can configure multiple vCenter / vSphere / ESX connections using this structure:

```
%centreon_vmware_config = (
    vsphere_server => {
                    'default' => {'url' => 'https://vcenter/sdk',
                                 'username' => 'XXXXXXX',
                                 'password' => 'XXXXXX'},
                    'other' => {'url' => 'https://other_vcenter/sdk',
                                 'username' => 'XXXXXXX',
                                 'password' => 'XXXXXX'},
                    },
    port => 5700
);
1;
```

Notice: use "CENTREONVMWARECONTAINER" host macro definition to select your configuration.

The "vsphere_server" attribute allows you to configure access to different VirtualCenter. It is necessary to have at least the entry 'default'. So, if you have only one vcenter, you can configure it with the name "default".
The "url" attribute allows you to configure the URL of the vcenter.
The "username" attribute allows you to configure the user who can connect to the vcenter. This user must have at least "read only" access to the vcenter.
The "password" attribute allows you to configure the password of the user.
The "port" attribute allows you to configure the listening port of "centreon-vmware" connector.

System configuration

The daemon "centreon_vmware" is a system service that must be started by default. After installation and configuration, you will have to perform the following procedure.

With SysV (Enterprise Linux 6 compatible distributions)

```
chkconfig centreon_vmware on
service centreon_vmware start
```

With SystemD (Enterprise Linux 7 compatible distributions)

```
systemctl enable centreon_vmware
systemctl start centreon_vmware
```

Checking the daemon configuration
Please make sure that the daemon configuration works fine, by looking for errors in /var/log/centreon/centreon_vmware.log.